# Kendo UI MVC Password

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, textbox, passwords

How can I hide the password in textbox by using kendo. Normally I can hide by using attribute that [Datatype(Datatype.Password)] with using PasswordFor. But In kendo I can't work attributes to hide password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use fluent syntax:

```
@(Html.Kendo()
     .TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
     .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "password" }))
```